# Nearley Tokenizers vs Rules

Tags: definition, nearley

I'm pretty new to [nearly.js](https://nearley.js.org), and I would like to know what tokenizers/lexers do compared to rules, according to the website:

> By default, nearley splits the input into a stream of characters. This is called scannerless parsing.
>   A tokenizer splits the input into a stream of larger units called tokens. This happens in a separate stage before parsing. For example, a tokenizer might convert `512 + 10` into `["512", "+", "10"]`: notice how it removed the whitespace, and combined multi-digit numbers into a single number.

Wouldn't that be the same as:

```
Math -> Number _ "+" _ Number
Number -> [0-9]:+
```

I don't see what the purpose of lexers are. I see that rules are always useable in this case and there is no need for lexers.

Comment: Lexers sometimes make use of regular expressions that determine if you are matching on keywords so you can apply the rules of a language.
https://nearley.js.org/docs/tokenizers

Comment: But rules can also be used in this case right?

Comment: What you are seeing is an example of essentially a pre-built lexer. The benefits are listed on the page and may not matter on a grammar this simple.
`…often makes your parser faster by more than an order of magnitude.`
`…allows you to write cleaner, more maintainable grammars.` `…helps avoid ambiguous grammars in some cases. For example, a tokenizer can easily tell you that superclass is a single keyword, not a sequence of super and class keywords.`
`…gives you lexical information such as line numbers for each token. This lets you make better error messages.`

Comment: @DanielGale Could you give an example of a practical use for lexers, and post it as an answer?

Answer (score 4):

After fiddling around with them, I found out the use of tokenizers, say we had the following:

```
Keyword -> "if"|"else"
Identifier -> [a-zA-Z_]+
```

This won't work, if we try compiling this, we get ambiguous grammar, "if" will be matched as both a keyword *and* an Identifier, a tokenizer however:

```
{
"keyword": /if|else/
"identifier": /[a-zA-Z_]+/
}
```

Trying to compile this will not result in ambiguous grammar, because tokenizers are smart (at least the one shown in this example, which is Moo).